# limit and boundedness of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

good people! I am reading limit in real analysis, and stuck on a problem: If $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ has a limit at every point, then $f$ is bounded.Is this true for $f:(a,b)\to \Bbb R$? Thank you.

Comment: The proof of the first statement involves completeness of real numbers and is not trivial. Do you seek this proof?

Answer (score 1):

No: for example $f(x) = \frac1x$ on $(0,1)$